# Java Wizard conditional next page

Tags: java, wizard

I'm using CJWizard to create a 2 page wizard where the second page is based on the choice of the first page.

In total therefore I have 3 pages of the wizard.

```
public class WizardTest extends JDialog
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        WizardTest test = new WizardTest();
        test.setVisible(true);
    }

    public WizardTest()
    {
        final WizardContainer wc
                = new WizardContainer(new TestFactory(),
                        new TitledPageTemplate(),
                        new StackWizardSettings());

        wc.addWizardListener(new WizardListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCanceled(List<WizardPage> path, WizardSettings settings)
            {
                WizardTest.this.dispose();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinished(List<WizardPage> path, WizardSettings settings)
            {
                WizardTest.this.dispose();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageChanged(WizardPage newPage, List<WizardPage> path)
            {
                WizardTest.this.setTitle(newPage.getDescription());
            }
        });

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.getContentPane().add(wc);
        this.pack();
    }

    private class TestFactory extends APageFactory
    {

        private final WizardPage[] pages =
        {
            new WizardPage("One", "First Page")
            {
                {
                    String[] choices =
                    {
                        "Two", "Three"
                    };
                    JComboBox jComboBox = new JComboBox(new DefaultComboBoxModel(choices));
                    jComboBox.setName("nextPage");
                    add(new JLabel("Which Page Next?"));
                    add(jComboBox);
                }
            },
            new WizardPage("Two", "Second Page")
            {
                {
                    add(new JLabel("Two!"));
                    setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                }

                @Override
                public void rendering(List<WizardPage> path, WizardSettings settings)
                {
                    super.rendering(path, settings);
                    setFinishEnabled(true);
                    setNextEnabled(false);
                }

            },
            new WizardPage("Three", "Third Page")
            {
                {
                    add(new JLabel("Three!"));
                    setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
                }

                @Override
                public void rendering(List<WizardPage> path, WizardSettings settings)
                {
                    super.rendering(path, settings);
                    setFinishEnabled(true);
                    setNextEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        };

        @Override
        public WizardPage createPage(List<WizardPage> path,
                WizardSettings settings)
        {
            WizardPage page;

            if (path.size() == 1)
            {
                String assignmentSelection = (String) settings.get("nextPage");
                if (assignmentSelection.equalsIgnoreCase("Three"))
                {
                    page = pages[path.size() + 1];
                }
                else
                {
                    page = pages[path.size()];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                page = pages[path.size()];
            }
            return page;
        }
    }
}
```

the above works only on the first visit of the wizard if I go back to the first page from the (chosen) second page and change choice in the first page  the createPage() is not called again and the already created page is shown.

How can I erase the previous choices and get back to first page without being shown always the original choice?

Answer (score 0):

Every Page can extends the `WizardPage`, so you can use the method : `getNextPage`
and change as you want the next wizardPage, they can be Identified by the name you use in the Constructor...
an Example of conditional Page flow:

```
public IWizardPage getNextPage() {
            // If they have complaints, go to the normal next page
            if (radioButtonRookies.getSelection()) {
                return super.getNextPage();
            }
            // No complaints? Short-circuit the rest of the pages
            return getWizard().getPage("generator");
        }
```

Comment: I can't use super.getNextPage() because I need to target a page index not next(), and I can't do it from the WizardPage because then I should pass an array of possible pages to every single WizardPage. This seems convoluted at best.